# How to print a part of a string in kotlin and why am I getting this error?

Tags: kotlin

```
val me = "Hello I am learning Kotlin"
fun main(){
    println(me[1,10])
}
```

I am getting "Too many arguments for public open fun get(index: Int): Char defined in kotlin.String" error at line 3 why? And How can I print a part of a string in kotlin.
According to https://kotlinlang.org/docs/operator-overloading.html#indexed-access-operator line 3 should work but its giving me too many arguments ERROR.

Comment: Do you want to print the 2nd _and_ 11th characters of the string (`e `)? (Remember that array indices start at 0 in Kotlin.) Or the 2nd _to_ 11th characters of the strong (`ello I am `)? Or starting at the 2nd and stopping before the 11th (`ello I am`)? Or something else?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The indexed operator function for a String only takes one argument. The documentation that you linked to is showing you how indexed operator overloads are interpreted *if you define them that way*. The one for String is only defined for one argument.

However, you can define your own extension function for String like this, and then your syntax would work:

```
operator fun String.get(firstIndex: Int, vararg otherIndices: Int) = buildString {
    append(this@get[firstIndex])
    for (i in otherIndices) append(this@get[i])
}
```